# Are there any Christian denominations that assure equality with God?

Tags: nature-of-god, denomination-survey, nature-of-man

Christianity, in general, is a [monotheistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytheism#Christianity) religion and confirms the existence of a single god.

But in the Trinity God exists in three forms. And the three forms are equal except for [relational](https://www.gotquestions.org/subordination-Trinity.html) differences.

It is well-known that we are not equal to God in at least many or all aspects. But my doubt is about the possibility of becoming God in all aspects at any point in time (includes post-death).

**Can a human *become* God, in all aspects, according to *any* denomination?**

No restrictions on human or time or place are assumed. I mean one is allowed to assume any human, any time (before or after death), any place (universe or heaven).

Comment: This question requires clarity, definition and detail. Scripture tells us that 'now are we the sons of God and it doth not yet appear what we shall be', 1 John 3:2. Jesus quotes the psalm 'Said I not, ye are gods ?' John 10:34. So the question, as it stands, cannot be answered without some editing. And this is, in any case, a very broad subject. It arguably falls into the category of 'philosophical'.

Comment: Are you wanting to know if there are monotheistic/Trinitarian denominations which say we can become God(s), or does the Mormon doctrine of [exaltation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exaltation_(Mormonism)) count too?

Comment: @curiousdannii From any doctrine, the first two paragraphs are just the reflection of my knowledge on broad domains.

Comment: @NigelJ, the question does not require any further "*clarity, definition and detail*", nor is broad or philosophical.  It simply asks whether any denominations have this belief.  It's a simple "yes" or "no" question that can easily be confirmed by the existence of such denominations.

Comment: @RayButterworth It would appear that on a biblical basis the answer can only be no, what with the "my thoughts are not as your thoughts" etc, but I'll be interested to see if there is a yes to this.

Comment: @RayButterworth Until the OP defines what they mean by 'god' it is not possible to say whether any denomination holds such a position.

Comment: I find it interesting that of the two answers so far, both responding "yes" and providing an example of such a denomination, one has only upvotes and no comments, while mine has only downvotes and comments questioning the validity of the example's doctrines. Why such a difference in response?  (What's even more interesting is that while we don't know each other, both of us happen to live in the same small city comprising .0015% of the world's population.)

Comment: @NigelJ, The statement "*Man Can Become God*" seems quite clear regardless of the OP's definition of "god".  There really *are* denominations that believe our ultimate destiny is to become God.  (I'm neither defending nor denying that doctrine, simply pointing out that it exists.)

Comment: The Mormon church is one denomination that makes this claim.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast, "*my thoughts are not as your thoughts*" is true now. But some denominations believe that the goal of a Christian is to develop God-like character, to change their minds to be like God's.  In the world to come, they *will* be like God's. [Repentance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repentance#Etymology) is translated from μετάνοια (metanoia), *meaning "after/behind one's mind", … the whole compound means: 'to think differently after'. … a change of mind and change of conduct, "change of mind and heart", or, "change of consciousness"*

Comment: @RayButterworth I was under the impression that one was to attempt to model their life after Christ {the Son} (minor distinction) since his nature is both human and divine, while the Father is solely divine ..  but with so many denominations, I can see a variety of approaches being in place.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast, the teaching is that in becoming Jesus, Christ gave up his divinity and while living as a human managed (with help of the holy spirit) to remain divine in character. ("*Instead, he gave up his divine privileges; he took the humble position of a slave and was born as a human being.* — Phil 2:7 NLT).  With that example, Christians can know that, with God's help, the goal *is* possible, though not instantaneously and not without falling back occasionally.  That is, as a human one should strive for divinity.

Comment: @BenSmith Does the LDS Church teach that man can become uncreated and self-existent as is  I AM THAT I AM?

Comment: @MikeBorden The (very) short(ened) answer to that is that it teaches man to already be that, in a sense. No creatio ex nihilo. I have trouble accessing the church website rn, but one keyword to search in D&C would be "co-eternal".

Answer (score 4):

Almost all Christian denominations hold that God is fundamentally different from Humans, particularly in that God is uncreated, eternal and the creator of everything that is. Humans thus cannot *become* God.

The only denomination I know of that teaches that Humans can become equal with God (and can in fact become gods) is [The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Church_of_Jesus_Christ_of_Latter-day_Saints), also called the Mormon Church.

> [In LDS doctrine, the goal of each adherent is to receive "exaltation" through the atonement of Jesus. If a person receives exaltation, they inherit all the attributes of God the Father, including godhood. Mormons believe that these people will become gods and goddesses in the afterlife, and will have "all power, glory, dominion, and knowledge"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mormon_cosmology#:%7E:text=If%20a%20person%20receives%20exaltation,%2C%20dominion%2C%20and%20knowledge%22.).

Comment: While I think this answer could benefit from being extended, it is good in that it highlights a major point: In most denominations, humans are created beings fundamentally different from the creator. The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-Day Saints teaches that all humans are literally children of God, and as such NOT fundamentally different, just as children are not fundamentally different from adults. And the differences that there are due to our fallen nature are (have been? will be?) overcome by Jesus.

Comment: Rather than relying on Wikipedia (which I doubt any of us believe adequately reflects anyone's canon... ), here's the LDS Topical Guide for [Man, Potential to Become like Heavenly Father](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/tg/man-potential-to-become-like-heavenly-father?lang=eng). That's a list of Biblical and LDS Scriptural references to support our belief.

Comment: @JBH I struggled to find a page on the LDS site that *describes* the doctrine. The page you link, while somewhat helpful, is a one sentence summary of the doctrine with some bible references they believe support it. I went with a quote that described the doctrine in more detail. The Wikipedia page has references for those that want to follow up.

Comment: Ah! Try [this statement from the Church](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/gospel-topics-essays/becoming-like-god?lang=eng), [this from Lorenzo Snow](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/teachings-of-presidents-of-the-church-lorenzo-snow/chapter-5-the-grand-destiny-of-the-faithful?lang=eng), and [this chapter from the Foundations of the Restoration teacher manual](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/foundations-of-the-restoration-teacher-manual/lesson-17-gospel-teachings-in-nauvoo?lang=eng).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there *are* Christian denominations that believe that man will become equal to God.
The 5<sup>th</sup> Commandment, to honour one's parents, would leave us still subordinate, even though equal.

Building this family is in fact the entire purpose of God's creation.

Many of these denominations have "Church of God" in their names (though not all denominations with that name share these beliefs).

Here is one example:

> Regrettably, the Trinity doctrine has been a major barrier to clear
> comprehension of the biblical truth that God is a divine family.
>
> The God family is headed by the Father and presently consists of God
> the Father and God the Son, Jesus Christ. Their plan and desire is
> fully focused on "bringing many sons [and daughters] to glory"
> (Hebrews 2:10). This has been planned from the beginning.
>
> Jesus Christ is "the firstborn from the dead" (Colossians 1:18)—"the
> firstborn among many brethren" (Romans 8:29). These passages mean that
> many more are going to join the family as divine spirit beings like
> the Father and Christ at the first resurrection, when the righteous
> are raised to everlasting life (see 1 Corinthians 15:49-54; 1 John
> 3:1-2; Revelation 20:6).
>
> Those who are truly converted and have received God's Holy Spirit are
> already reckoned to be a part of the family (again, see Ephesians
> 3:14-15). They await the final step at the second coming.
>
> At that time Jesus "will transform our lowly body that it may be
> conformed to His glorious body" (Philippians 3:21). Then it can be
> said in its fullest sense, "I will be a Father to you, and you shall
> be My sons and daughters, says the Lord Almighty" (2 Corinthians
> 6:18).
>
> — from [10 Things You Should Know About God | United Church of God](https://www.ucg.org/the-good-news/10-things-you-should-know-about-god)

Additional evidence of their belief that man can become God:

[God Became Man so Man Can Become God: The Chief Cornerstone | United Church of God](https://www.ucg.org/sermons/god-became-man-so-man-can-become-god-the-chief-cornerstone)

And supporting evidence from early Christianity:

[Early Theologians on Becoming Divine | United Church of God](https://www.ucg.org/bible-study-tools/booklets/why-were-you-born/early-theologians-on-becoming-divine)

Comment: The question asks if we will be like God in every aspect, not whether we will be sons of God.

Comment: @MikeBorden, no, the question asks if any denominations believe we will become God. There really are denominations that believe that, and I gave an example of one, the United Church of God. Jesus was the firstborn son of the Father. These denominations believe that saved Christians will become his younger siblings. And children are generally equal to their siblings and parents in all aspects except for deferring to the parents in terms of authority.  They say: "*We believe that the reason for mankind's existence is literally to be born as spirit beings into the family of God *".

Comment: @MikeBorden  trinitarians say that being son of God means Jesus is God.  Sharing the same nature and all that.

Comment: "In all aspects" is a qualifier in the question.  Does the United Church of God teach that people will become uncreated and self-existent?

Comment: @Kris A major distinction exists between an only begotten Son (Jesus) and sons by creation and adoption (believers).

Comment: @MikeBorden While I think that's true for most, or many, denominations, I am not so certain that it is true for all denominations.

Comment: @MikeBorden You ask if the UCG teaches that people will become "uncreated and self-existent." That's a phrase from your own theology that you may sincerely believe is applicable universally - but it's not believed universally and is not a condition of the OP's question. In other words, the question has greater implications than "equal with God in all aspects as understood by Mike Borden." That might even be the point of the question.

Comment: @JBH The question asks about becoming like the Christian Triune God and assumes that we are, currently, not like Him in many or possibly all aspects.  The God in the question is uncreated and self-existent.

Comment: @MikeBorden, consider their position like this: you were created in your physical  parents' image and you grew up to resemble them. They aren't necessarily bigger or stronger or smarter or better than you. The same is true of your siblings with respect to both you and your parents. In all ways you are all equally human, with the single exception of the 5th commandment relationship. This relationship of honour, respect, etc. exists despite the fact that we are physically equivalent human beings.  The CoG believes that this situation applies, at a spiritual level, to baptized Christians and God.

Comment: To be clear, there are a lot of churches and denominations that are called [Church of God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_of_God), and they do not all share the same doctines on this or many other issues.

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica, I've clarified it, thanks.  In your linked page they would correspond most closely to the "Armstrongism" group.

Comment: I'm not trying to push, I'm just incredulous.  Does CoG teach that God is self-existent?  Does it teach that believers will become self-existent?

Comment: @MikeBorden, I'm not a member of that or any other related church, so I can't say definitively.  I *do* know that they believe that both the Father and Son are uncreated and have always existed. So in that sense of "self-existent", it will be true of them but not of any new beings (who are "conceived" at baptism and "born" at Christ's return). In the sense of not needing anyone or anything else in order to exist, I don't know.  (As adult humans we can exist without our parents, but most of us choose to remain part of their family. God's children would certainly choose to remain in his family.)